# Data does not gets added in UIBubbleTableView in iOS

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, xmppframework, reloaddata, uibubbletableview

I am new to iOS and i am working on chat application where i try to receive messages through XMPP and pass that received message to chat table view(UIBubbleTableView).
But when i try to add that message in table view array the array becomes null, and hence the data does not gets added to table view.

When i try to store some hardcoded messages in that array in viewDidLoad method, it is showing those message on table view.

Below is my method which is invoked when there is a message received in XMPP class.

```
- (void)newMessageReceived:(NSString *)messageContent {

NSBubbleData *newdata = [NSBubbleData dataWithText: messageContent date:      [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] type:BubbleTypeSomeoneElse];
bubbleData1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[bubbleData1 addObject:newdata];
_bubbleTable.bubbleDataSource=self;

      [_bubbleTable reloadData];

}
```

and above  method receives data using XMPP method given below-

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message {



NSString *msg = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
NSString *from = [[message attributeForName:@"from"] stringValue];

NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[m setObject:msg forKey:@"msg"];
[m setObject:from forKey:@"sender"];

ChatController *chat=[[ChatController alloc]init];
[chat newMessageReceived:[m valueForKey:@"msg"]];

}
```

I am able to get the new message in newMessageRecieved method, but is does not get added to bubble tableview.
Can anyone help me out to solve this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `[bubbleData1 addObject:newdata33];` shouldn't this be without the 33? So `[bubbleData1 addObject:newdata];`

Comment: Are you doing anything asynchronously and need to get back to the main thread?

Comment: how to clear all the asynchronous tasks get back to main thread? can you please tell me.

Comment: i did tried this      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 [_bubbleTable reloadData];  });   but still not working

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Does UIBubbleTableView subclass UITableView?

Comment: yes it does subclass

Comment: Have you implemented tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:?

Comment: no. i have implemented these two methods --   #pragma mark - UIBubbleTableViewDataSource implementation

- (NSInteger)rowsForBubbleTable:(UIBubbleTableView *)tableView
{
    return [bubbleData1 count];
}

- (NSBubbleData *)bubbleTableView:(UIBubbleTableView *)tableView dataForRow:(NSInteger)row
{
    return [bubbleData1 objectAtIndex:row];
}

Comment: can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

In there you should add your content to the UITableViewCell or a custom subclass of it and then it displays the cells.

[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4-kjME5iP8)